# You have been watching too much music song

Tags: grammar

I have downloaded a lots of youtube music song in my computer.

I played them to my son.

It's going to be bed soon and I was telling him that was the last one.

He refused and wanted to watch more.

> "You have been watching too much **music song/monitor**?"

Would it sound awkward for using these word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean **music videos**, and it would be "too *many*", not "too *much*", since these are *countable*.

> You've been watching **too many music videos**.  Turn them off and go to bed.

[A famous music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)